# Python: Finding the average using sum/len after already rounding numbers

Tags: python, arrays, average

I am trying to build a program where the user enters the weight (into an ARRAY) on Earth in pounds. The program converts the weight into what it would weigh on the Moon.
Then in the end, I want it to take the stored array and calculate the average weight on the Moon of the inputted weights.

Using the code below, it gives me "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable".
****How do I get the average to calculate? Any help is appreciated!****
my code is here [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev1r0.png)

```py
numlist = list()
lbs = float(input("Enter a weight of person (Enter –1 to exit): "))
while (lbs != -1 ):
    numlist.append(lbs)
    moon_weight = (lbs / 9.81) * 1.622
    limited_float = round(moon_weight)
    print ('This person weighs', limited_float, 'pounds on the moon.')
    lbs = eval(input("Enter a next weight (Enter –1 to exit): "))

average = sum(moon_weight) / len(numlist)
print ('Average of weights on the moon:', average)
```

**Edit :** since `while True` is still new to me, I do not want to just use someone elses work. With the wonderful help of others, this is what I was able to do.

```
numlist = list()
lbs = float(input("Enter a weight of person (Enter –1 to exit): "))
while (lbs != -1 ):
    moon_weight = (lbs / 9.81) * 1.622
    limited_float = round(moon_weight)
    numlist.append(moon_weight)
    print ('This person weighs', limited_float, 'pounds on the moon.')
    lbs = eval(input("Enter a next weight (Enter –1 to exit): "))

average = round(sum(numlist) / len(numlist))
print ('Average of weights on the moon:', average)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `moon_weight` to `numlist` (instead of `lbs`), and then compute `sum(numlist) / len(numlist)` instead of `sum(moon_weight) / len(numlist)`.

Comment: Could you possibly show me where you said I should add `moon_weight` to  `numlist`

Comment: @notsomasterprogrammer No, you'll figure it out I'm sure. Plenty of spoonfeeding answers here already.

Comment: I apologize for needing help, this is my first programming class ever.

Comment: I would rather understand why I am doing something wrong so I can prevent the same mistakes in the future, rather than just accepting spoonfed answers and not understanding for said corrections worked. But 'Thanks'

Comment: @notsomasterprogrammer I'm here to answer questions for everyone's benefit, I'm not a personal teacher (for free). "Please show me" or "please teach me" are not questions, and are not useful to anyone except you. It's not my job to find out exactly where your gap in knowledge lies - what it is exactly you don't understand. As I said, I'm sure you'll figure it out based on the answers here compared to your own.

Comment: When I implemented your suggestion, it still did not work. Clearly, I was not understanding what you were saying, hence me asking you to elaborate. No one said it was 'your job' to do anything. It is sad that someone can not receive more help from you specifically if they do not understand what you said the first time. I apologize that my ignorant programming brain cannot work at your level. Maybe one day I can be as great as you! Until then, I will keep working through suggestions until I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Correction to code

```
numlist = [] # more standard than numlist = list()
while True:
    # Only need one input
    lbs = input("Enter a weight of person (Enter -1 to exit): ")
    if lbs == '-1' or lbs == '':
        break                           # done on -1 or empty string
    
    lbs = float(lbs)                    # float conversion
    moon_weight = (lbs/9.81)*1.622
    numlist.append(moon_weight)         # add moon weight
    print(f'This person weighs {round(moon_weight)} pounds on the moon')  # using string interpolation  # using string interpolation

# String interpolation and show two decimal places i.e. .2f
print(f'Average of weights on the moon: {sum(numlist) /len(numlist):.2f}')
```

**Test**

```
Enter a weight of person (Enter -1 to exit): 100
This person weighs 17 pounds on the moon
Enter a weight of person (Enter -1 to exit): 150
This person weighs 25 pounds on the moon
Enter a weight of person (Enter -1 to exit): 200
This person weighs 33 pounds on the moon
Enter a weight of person (Enter -1 to exit): -1
Average of weights on the moon: 24.80
```

**Explanation**

Line:

```
print(f'Average of weights on the moon: {sum(numlist) /len(numlist):.2f}')
```

Is equivalent to:

```
average = sum(numlist) /len(numlist)
average_fmt = round(average, 2)        # round to 2 decimal places
print('Average of weights on the moon: ', average_fmt)
```

That's because:

```
f'Average of weights on the moon: {sum(numlist) /len(numlist):.2f}'
```

is a string interpolation (i.e. special string that allows expressions inside that are evaluated to a final string).

Information on [String interpolation](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/string-interpolation)

Items with {} are evaluated as expressions.  The ':' within {} identifies is allows a format specifier to be added (e.g. '.2f' provides two decimal places).

**Simpler While Loop and Output**

```
numlist = [] # more standard than numlist = list()
lbs = ''     # initial value so we will enter while loop
while lbs != -1:
    lbs = input("Enter a weight of person (Enter -1 to exit): ")
    if lbs != '-1':
      print(lbs)
      lbs = float(lbs)                    # float conversion
      moon_weight = (lbs/9.81)*1.622
      numlist.append(moon_weight)         # add moon weight
      print('This person weighs', round(moon_weight), 'pounds on the moon')  # using string interpolation  # using string interpolation
    else:
        break
     
if len(numlist) > 0:
    print('Average of weights on the moon: ', round(sum(numlist) /len(numlist), 2))
else:
    print('No weights entered')
```

Comment: Im not following on how what you provided at the end calculates the average. Could you elaborate for me?

Comment: @notsomasterprogrammer--added more explanation.  Does this help?

Comment: That does make sense. I was not aware of  String Interpolation. That is too advanced for me right now but I greatly appreciate you introducing a new concept to me. I will be able to use that in the future! I am still trying to understand the `while True` and `breaks` usage. I know that is the standard. I will do more research on that in order to help me simplify my programs. Thank you for your pseudocode explanation, as well. I will begin applying those to this program and future ones!

Comment: @notsomasterprogrammer--added a simpler while loop example.  Are you familiar with this form of while loop?  This doesn't use string interpolation but notice items in the print statement have been broken into multiple pieces.  String interpolation avoids this (string interpolation is popular in many languages i.e. [string interpolation languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation)

Comment: Yes, that looks more familiar! I know that that is not the most efficient way of programming but it is the level I am at right now I think. I have edited my original post to what I was able to correct and get to work if you would like to look at it. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @notsomasterprogrammer--is there a reason you call eval?  This is frowned upon except for very special cases, so shouldn't be used if you're new to the language.  Note: [why is eval dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: I used eval because that is what was showed to us in the course content. I have used it ever week. I did not know this was a problem! I will research this more!

Comment: @notsomasterprogrammer--Eval is a charged topic so that's why I'm surprised you're using it.  It's simple and straightforward but don't use in a job interview unless you can communicate that you're fully aware of its dangers and know why its safe for this particular application.  In your case, it's safe because this is homework rather than an application which takes inputs from random users.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this is what you are looking for.
I think you are confusing the variable moon_weight with the list numlist.
Here is a working example of how you can do this.

```
moon_weights_list = list()
while True:
    lbs = float(input("Enter a weight of person (Enter –1 to exit): "))
    if lbs == -1 :
        break

    moon_weight = (lbs / 9.81) * 1.622
    moon_weights_list.append(moon_weight)

    limited_float = round(moon_weight)
    print ('This person weighs', limited_float, 'pounds on the moon.')

average = sum(moon_weights_list) / len(moon_weights_list)
print('Average of weights on the moon:', average)
```

To point out the specific problem you are making I'll try explaining the error that is raised on this line :

```
average = sum(moon_weight) / len(numlist)
```

The error :

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Is being raised by the function `sum()` which takes an iterable as an argument.

- **So what's an iterable?**

1. It's an instance of a class that implements the `__iter__` and `__next__`.
2. A simpler definition is : the stuff that for loop for example can iterate through. like lists, sets, dicts, typles, etc.....

So back to your code, the `sum(moon_weight)` function takes as an argument `moon_weight` which supposedly contains a float, (`moon_weight = (lbs / 9.81) * 1.622`).

Code as the following  :

```
average = sum(numlist) / len(numlist)
```

would calculate the average of the inputed values (for the earth not the moon) for example.

What comes next is finding a way to create a list which contains the values for the moon, and then passing it the the two functions sum() and len(). As I did in the code included above.

Comment: This works exactly how I want it. I just now need to figure out what is making this program right versus what is not working properly in mine. I have not learned/or do not understand the `while True` and `breaks` yet. I will keep at it though because I do not just want to use another persons work. Thank you so much!

Comment: If that what you really think than hats off to you, I edited the post and tried to add a bit more of an explanation,

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out what part was messed up. I knew I obviously wasnt picking the correct variable for the average but I did not understand what I was mixing up. Per your advice, and correct me if I am not completely understanding it, I did not append the user inputted elements in `numlist` to my conversion of those elements in `moon_weight`. Therefore, when I used `numlist`, it was not using the calculations in `moon_weight`.

Comment: Yup, exactly. So you can either (1) create a new list then append the converted elements to it and finally use it to calculate the sum() and len() for the average or (2) use the numlist and instead of appending the lbs, u append the moon_weight values and then use it at the end for the sum() and len() values

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and guidance! This is extremely new to me and I am equivalent to that of a pre-k level programming. Knowing my mistakes and being able to know why it is wrong helps me understand better. I have edited my original post to reflect what I corrected if you would like to look at it.
I will keep utilizing the methods you used in order to further my programming abilities.